# What steps it takes to add GitHub repo to Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, github, composer-php

I would like to use following GitHub repo in my Laravel application:

https://github.com/khanamiryan/php-qrcode-detector-decoder

It doesn't have composer set up nor it can be found from Packagist. I tried to use regular php_require but it tells me "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\QrReader' not found".

Using php_require feels wrong anyways. What is the correct way to handle situation like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273746/composer-packages-autoloading-non-class-based-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new directory in your app root

```
mkdir third-party
cd third-party
```

Clone the repo

```
git clone https://github.com/khanamiryan/php-qrcode-detector-decoder
```

Edit your composer.json file and add it to the classmap:

```
"classmap": [
    "database",
    "third-party/php-qrcode-detector-decoder"
],
```

Update class maps:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

And you should see in your `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`

```
'Zxing\\Binarizer' => $baseDir . '/third-party/php-qrcode-detector-decoder/lib/Binarizer.php',
'Zxing\\BinaryBitmap' => $baseDir . '/third-party/php-qrcode-detector-decoder/lib/BinaryBitmap.php',
...
```

Then you just have to use it:

```
use Zxing\Reader;
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Your and MacPrawns answer helped me to get things rolling.

Answer (score 0):

I think the major class is QrReader(). You can use this class as controller class but you need to extend the controller class and fix imports. You can import this class as third party class on your laravel controller too.
Do you need to use QrReader() class?
Then just put all the library files App\Libraries and the main class in App\classes. Or you can do in our own way too. But follow the following
1) Manage namespaces
2) import the class to your controller by using

```
use App\classes\QrReader
```

Finally, you will have access to all the methods defined in the imported class. But in you main class you need to correct the path and dependencies of libraries files.

You can try this tutorial too:
[How to use external classes](http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/)

You can read the discussion here (Nice)
[Best way to import third party classes](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/best-way-to-import-third-party-class)

Comment: What do you think about forking the existing repo, adding the composer file and submitting it to Packagist? Would that be all to get this to work properly? Then I could just add necessary lines to config/app.php (providers and aliases).

Comment: Yes you can do that, but i think yo will face problem of dependencies. you need to do lil bit more with that approach i think.
Nice idea but for me i will go with the easy way... we can do with composer and that will be the good way , managed way to do tooo... I need to try once to see.

Comment: the answer by "Antonio Carlos Ribeiro" is the best that you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Because this github project does not have a composer.json file, I don't think you can use it with composer.

However, you could branch the repo, make your own copy, and add a composer file to it. Then you'd be able to add it to your main project's composer.json file:

```
{
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/your-git-account/php-qrcode-detector-decoder"
    }
],
"require": {
    "your-git-account/php-qrcode-detector-decoder": "dev-master"
}
```

Hope this helps!

(Source https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository)

Comment: I like this way. What about namespaces? Should I add something to config\app.php?

Comment: Right, so once the composer files have been included (running composer update your-git-account/php-qrcode-detector-decoder) that just makes the code available locally for your Laravel app to use.

To actually use the code, you'll probably want to use a [https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers](service provider) or something like that to wrap this module's abilities.